# The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique `id` property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I know I have to use getRowId, but how do I use `statId` in oppose to `id`? It is unique. Or generate an `id` property for each one of them?

> Error: MUI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique `id` property.
> Alternatively, you can use the `getRowId` prop to specify a custom id for each row.
> A row was provided without id in the rows prop:
> {"statId":813183,"teamId":3,"season":2021,"name":"Atlanta Hawks","team":"ATL","wins":41,"losses":31,"fieldGoalsMade":3492.1,"fieldGoalsAttempted":7468.1,"fieldGoalsPercentage":55.6,"twoPointersMade":2427.9,"twoPointersAttempted":4612.1,"twoPointersPercentage":62.5,"threePointersMade":1064.2,"threePointersAttempted":2856,"threePointersPercentage":44.3,"freeThrowsMade":1684.8,"freeThrowsAttempted":2074.8,"freeThrowsPercentage":96.5,"offensiveRebounds":903.6,"defensiveRebounds":3002.2,"rebounds":3905.9,"assists":2065.3,"steals":598.1,"blockedShots":405.4,"turnovers":1086.7,"personalFouls":1655.1,"points":9733.2,"doubleDoubles":120.1,"tripleDoubles":1.4}

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridRowIdGetter } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { Grid, Paper, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import Skeleton from '@mui/material/Skeleton';
import { blue } from '@mui/material/colors';

import FormOne from './../src/FormOne';
import { TeamSeason } from './../src/lib/interfaces/TeamSeason';

const LoadingSkeleton = () => (
  <Box
    sx={{
      height: 'max-content',
    }}
  >
    {[...Array(10)].map((_, index) => (
      <Skeleton variant="rectangular" sx={{ my: 4, mx: 1 }} key={index} />
    ))}
  </Box>
);

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: 'statId', headerName: 'Stat ID' },
  { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 300 },
  { field: 'season', headerName: 'Season', width: 600 },
];

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(
      () =>
        fetch('https://localhost:7000/TeamSeason/2021')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setData(data);
            setLoading(false);
          }),
      3000
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container
      maxWidth={false}
      sx={{
        height: '100vh',
        overflow: 'auto',
        background: `linear-gradient(to right, ${blue[200]}, ${blue[500]})`,
      }}
    >
      <Container maxWidth="lg" sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 3 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }}>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <Paper sx={{ padding: 3 }}>
              <FormOne data={data} />
            </Paper>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <Paper sx={{ padding: 3 }}></Paper>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper sx={{ padding: 3 }}>
              <DataGrid
                sx={{ height: '650px' }} // either autoHeight or this
                rows={data}
                columns={columns}
                pageSize={10}
                // autoHeight
                rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
                disableSelectionOnClick
                disableColumnMenu
                disableColumnSelector
                components={{
                  LoadingOverlay: LoadingSkeleton,
                }}
                loading={loading}
              />
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

```
export interface TeamSeason {
  statId: number;
  teamId: number;
  season: number;
  name: string;
  team: string;
  wins: number;
  losses: number;
  fieldGoalsMade: number;
  fieldGoalsAttempted: number;
  fieldGoalsPercentage: number;
  twoPointersMade: number;
  twoPointersAttempted: number;
  twoPointersPercentage: number;
  threePointersMade: number;
  threePointersAttempted: number;
  threePointersPercentage: number;
  freeThrowsMade: number;
  freeThrowsAttempted: number;
  freeThrowsPercentage: number;
  offensiveRebounds: number;
  defensiveRebounds: number;
  rebounds: number;
  assists: number;
  steals: number;
  blockedShots: number;
  turnovers: number;
  personalFouls: number;
  points: number;
  doubleDoubles: number;
  tripleDoubles: number;
}
```

Answer (score 33):

You can use this in `DataGrid` props:

```
<DataGrid getRowId={(row) => row.statId} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried that but since it's typescript, I tried `getRowId={(row: TeamSeason) => row.statId}` which warned me that `row` must be `GridRowIdGetter` type.

Answer (score 11):

With this error keep in mind that iterations run on `keys` to act as unique identifiers for each row.  The `getRowId` attribute is looking to extrapolate a unique id from the row.

Here is an example solution:

```js
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
      { salary:53025, first_name:"Don" },
      { salary:63026, first_name:"Ted" },
      { salary:73027, first_name:"Bill" },
      { salary:83028, first_name:"Al" },
      { salary:23022, first_name:"Biff" },
   ];

   return (
      <div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}>
         <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            getRowId={(row: any) =>  row.first_name + row.salary}
         />
      </div>
```

or if you still have keys colliding you can try something like this

```
function generateRandom() {
    var length = 8,
        charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
        retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    return retVal;
}

   return (
      <div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}>
         <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            getRowId={(row: any) =>  generateRandom()}
         />
      </div>
```

More info can be found on the [MUI site here](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-definition/).

Answer (score 5):

if you are using MongoDB you should include this line
`getRowId={(row) => row._id}`
since MongoDB's ID is named _id this will look for the _id option and choose it as the unique ID

Answer (score 5):

I fetch data from data base, MongoDB, so this worked for me

```
  <DataGrid
    rows={usersData}
    disableSelectionOnClick
    columns={columns}
    pageSize={8}
    checkboxSelection
    getRowId={(row) => row._id}
    >
```

Answer (score 3):

Datagrid needs an id so you need column named "id" so

```
(row) => ({id:statId})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

that means your response object list doesn't has id attribute, find any uniq key from your data and use as id. Example-

```
<DataGrid rows={dataFromBackend} 
columns={columns} 
getRowId={(row: any) => row.uniqKeyfromBackend} 
/>
```