# Datagrid row have to have a unique id

Tags: reactjs

I made a data gird with data from the api, but i have a problem beacause error msg tells me that:
gridRowsUtils.js:13 Uncaught Error: MUI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique `id` property.
Alternatively, you can use the `getRowId` prop to specify a custom id for each row.
A row was provided without id in the rows prop:
"N"

my component looks like that:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TicketService from "../services/ticketService";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { FiTrash2, FiExternalLink } from "react-icons/fi"

import EventBus from "../utils/EventBus";

import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { DataGrid, GridActionsCellItem } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const AdminTickets = () => {

  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const refresh = () => {
    TicketService.getTickets();
    navigate("/tickets");

  }

    const deleteTicket = React.useCallback(
        (id) => () => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            TicketService.deleteTicket(id)
            setRows((prevRows) => prevRows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
            navigate("/tickets");
          });
        },
        [navigate],
    );

    const navigateToTicketDetails = React.useCallback(
      (id) => () => {
        navigate(`/tickets/details/${id}`);
      },[navigate],
    );

    const columns = [
        { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 150 },
        { field: 'title', headerName: 'Title', width: 250,editable: false },
        { field: 'subject', headerName: 'Subject', width: 250, editable: false,},
        {field: 'description', headerName: 'Description', width: 300, editable: false,},
        {field: 'createdAt',headerName: 'Created At',type: 'date', width: 150, editable: false, },
        { field: 'updatedAt', headerName: 'Updated At', type: 'date', width: 150, editable: false, },
        {
            field: 'actions',
            type: 'actions',
            headerName: 'Delete',
            width: 80,
            getActions: (params) => [
              <GridActionsCellItem
                icon={<FiTrash2 />}
                label="Delete"
                onClick={deleteTicket(params.id)}
              />
            ]
        },
        {
          field: 'actions1', type: 'actions', headerName: 'Details', width: 80, getActions: (params) => [
            <GridActionsCellItem
              label="Details"
              icon={<FiExternalLink />}
              onClick={navigateToTicketDetails(params.id)}
            />
          ]
        }
    ];

  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    TicketService.getTickets().then(
      (response) => {
        setRows(response.data);
      },
      (error) => {
        const _rows =
          (error.response &&
            error.response.data &&
            error.response.data.message) ||
          error.message ||
          error.toString();

        setRows(_rows);

        if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
          EventBus.dispatch("logout");
        }
      }
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: '95%', width: '100%' }}>
      <h3 className="tab-title">All Tickets</h3>
    <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      pageSize={10}
      rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
      checkboxSelection
      disableSelectionOnClick
    />
    </Box>
  );
};

export default AdminTickets;
```

I have tried add some id with row id but it didn't work.

Comment: Duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71644043/the-data-grid-component-requires-all-rows-to-have-a-unique-id-property

Comment: but if I add getRowId={(row: any) =>  generateRandom()} i cant write row:any because i have jsx file not typescript

Comment: you can use `getRowId={(row) => generateRandom()}`

Comment: if i add as you write i still have the same error

Answer (score 1):

According to [MUI](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-definition/#row-identifier):

> Each row must have a unique identifier.
>
> This identifier is used internally to identify the row in the various
> models—for instance, the row selection model—and to track the row
> across updates.
>
> By default, the data grid looks for a property named id in the data
> set to get that identifier.
>
> If the row's identifier is not called id, then you need to use the
> getRowId prop to tell the grid where it's located.

You could just add an id to each row of the `response.data`:

```
response.data.map((row, index) => row["id"] = index);
setRows(response.data);
```

**Or** you must provide it through the `getRowId` prop:

```
<DataGrid
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  pageSize={10}
  rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
  checkboxSelection
  disableSelectionOnClick
  getRowId={(row) => yourUniqueIdentifier} // here
/>
```

Comment: still have error

Comment: Provide a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) please.

Comment: I paste code but i can't paste everything because is my project for studies...

Comment: Hi, i've add getRowId={(row) => generateRandom()} and this function and it make unique id for the also fields: {
            field: 'actions',
            type: 'actions',
            headerName: 'Delete',
            width: 80,
            getActions: (params) => [
              <GridActionsCellItem
                icon={<FiTrash2 />}
                label="Delete"
                onClick={deleteUser(params.id)}
              />
            ]
        }